# How to hide UIRefreshControl when UISearchBar becomes active?

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I have a tableview that supports pull down to refresh and search (separately). If I pull down to refresh and immediately click the search bar, how can I hide the refreshControl?

Comment: don't put the search bar in the refreshcontrol view, make it separate from the tableview

Comment: Currently, the search bar is in a tableview.. the refresh control is separate (i.e. it is not in the same tableview).

Comment: can u do a screenschot of the tableview child on storyboard or some of ur code?

Comment: ok.. so there is a UISearchDisplayDelegate method called searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch that gets called before the search becomes active. The problem is, if I call [self.refreshControl endRefreshing] from this method, the refreshControl remains visible.. I've verified through logging that the refreshControl was on, and is successfully turned off after this call; however, it remains visible in the tableview. Any ideas?

Comment: self.tableView.contentOffest = CGPointMake(0, your_refresh_control_height);

Answer (score 2):

@Bejibun led me to the answer based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750194/how-to-hide-uirefreshcontrol-when-uisearchbar-becomes-active?s=a2750bb5-4947-415a-8ed7-acdeebeea1a5#comment40297886_25750194). Just need to set the `UITablevies` offset to `(0 - refresh_control_height)`.

so..

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0 - self.refreshControl.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I found so far is to disable the refresh completely while search bar is active.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
....

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    // Disable refresh control
    self.refreshControl = self.tableViewController.refreshControl;
    self.tableViewController.refreshControl = nil;
    return YES;
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{   
    //Restore refresh control
    self.tableViewController.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;
 }
```